# How to make elif statement and except ValueError repeat function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am on section 4 of the Udemy "Automate the Boring Stuff" course, which covers handling errors with try/except.

How can I get the script to run from the beginning if the user input is an invalid non-integer or negative integer?

```
print('How many cats do you have?')
numCat = input()
try:
    while True:
        if int(numCat) >= 4:
            print('That is a lot of kitties')
            break
        elif int(numCat) <= -1:
            print('You can not have '+str(numCat)+' kitties, try again')
            break
        else:
            print('That is not that many kitties')
            break
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter a number, try again')
```

Comment: If you handle the exception inside the `while` loop, you would keep looping over until `break`ing out. When you place entirely loop inside `try`/`except` block, you handle the exception and continue past the `except` block. -> you could move the `input` bit into the `while` loop and only handle `ValueError` where it actually could pop upL the `int`  constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of the loop if every path has a `break` in it?
You could do something like this:

```
cond = True
while cond:
    print('How many cats do you have?')
    numCat = input()
    try:
        cond = False
        if int(numCat) >= 4:
            print('That is a lot of kitties')
        elif int(numCat) <= -1:
            print('You can not have '+str(numCat)+' kitties, try again')
        else:
            print('That is not that many kitties')
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number, try again')
```

Or either with `break`

```
while True:
    print('How many cats do you have?')
    numCat = input()
    try:
        if int(numCat) >= 4:
            print('That is a lot of kitties')
        elif int(numCat) <= -1:
            print('You can not have '+str(numCat)+' kitties, try again')
        else:
            print('That is not that many kitties')
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number, try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do something like this:

BONUS: `isdigit` only counts positive numbers!

```
numCat = None
while True:
  numCat = input()
  if numCat.isdigit():
     break
  print('Please enter a positive number.')
if int(numCat) >= 4:
  print('That is a lot of kitties')
else:
  print('That is not that many kitties')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient solution or if there are better ones. But what I would do is loop through the try and let the user input again

```
print('How many cats do you have?')
numCat = input()
loopCount = 0
while loopCount == 0:
    numCat = input()
    try:
        while True:
            if int(numCat) >= 4:
                print('That is a lot of kitties')
                break
            elif int(numCat) <= -1:
                print('You can not have '+str(numCat)+' kitties, try again')
                break
            else:
                print('That is not that many kitties')
                break
        loopCount = 1
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number, try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

move your `try-except` block and `input` inside `while` loop to catch invalid inputs.

```
while True:
    print('How many cats do you have?')
    numCat = input()
    try:
        if int(numCat) >= 4:
            print('That is a lot of kitties')
            break
        elif int(numCat) <= -1:
            print('You can not have ' + str(numCat) + ' kitties, try again')
            break
        else:
            print('That is not that many kitties')
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number, try again')
```